# Hover over list item to change the attributes of a different div

Tags: javascript, css, class, hover

I am trying to make the attributes of a div change when a list item in a completely different div is hovered over.  I have used the code below but this doesn't seem to work. Can anybody help me understand what I should be doing differently please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hover {
color:red; 
}
</style>


<script type = "text/javascript">
$('.x').hover(function() {
//Mouse in event
$('.y').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
//Mouse out event
$('.y').removeClass('hover');
 });
</script>

</head>



<body>
<ul>
<div class = "x"> <li>  Hover over me </li> </div> 
</ul>

<div class = "y"> <p>  Result  </p> </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The tilbe(~) is a general sibling operator meaning that the two elements have to have the same parent (in this case the ul). I know of no way to do this through pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using javascript for this task.

I added a snippet that changes the div when the list item is hovered using jquery.

**Edit: Call the javascript code on the onload of the body**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hover {
color:red; 
}
</style>


<script type = "text/javascript">
var onLoad = function() {
  $('.x').hover(function() {
    //Mouse in event
    $('.y').addClass('hover');
  }, function() {
    //Mouse out event
    $('.y').removeClass('hover');
 });
}
</script>

</head>



<body onload="onLoad()">
<ul>
<div class = "x"> <li>  Hover over me </li> </div> 
</ul>

<div class = "y"> <p>  Result  </p> </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Shamun, that's exactly the sort of solution I was looking for but unfortunately I can't get my code to work.  I have added to my javascript (encased in <script> </script>)/ css / html as above but to no avail.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: @OneBigEgg can you post your new code so I can review it?

Comment: Not sure if this will come out OK in a comment:<style>
.hover {
   color:red; 
 }
</style>


<script type = "text/javascript">
$('.x').hover(function() {
    //Mouse in event
    $('.y').addClass('hover');
  }, function() {
    //Mouse out event
    $('.y').removeClass('hover');
  });
</script>

</head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <ul>
    <div class = "x"> <li>  Hover over me </li> </div> 
  </ul>

  <div class = "y"> <p>  Result  </p> </div>  
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please edit your post instead of using comments. It's unreadable this way

Comment: Hi Shamun, I have edited the original post as you suggested.  Thanks